# Ubuntu 16.04 install python-matplotlib 2.0.0

Tags: 16.04, apt, python

I'm wondering is it possible to use

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

to get a matplotlib version 2.0.0 or 2.1.0?

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib=2.0.0
```

is not working.
It seems I can only get 1.5.1 version.

Could any one give some suggestion? I don't wanna use pip to install library,because last time I met a mixinstall problem...

Thank in advance!

Comment: 2.0 and newer are in Ubuntu 17.04 and newer. An LTS (like 16.04) does *not* update software. That's why it's called "stable" - it's designed for enterprise users who need a "stable" workflow.

Answer (score 2):

Before you start - do not forget to remove python-matplotlib with
`sudo apt-get purge python-matplotlib`.

Then you may try to install matplotlib-2.1.0 with pip:

- `sudo pip install matplotlib` (for python2.7)
- `sudo pip3 install matplotlib` (for python3.5).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm wondering will pip cause some mixinstall problems? cuz last time I tried pip install, some problems happened.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't install matplotlib on my ubuntu 16.04 using python 3.5 
(ImportError: No module named '_tkinter').

Then after using python 3.6.4 everything worked well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I have newer version of matplotlib in my anaconda3.